# Linear Transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So I'm trying to find a way to do this:

Let $T$ be a Linear Transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that performs a horizontal shear that transforms $p_2$ into $p_2 - 2p_1$ (without changing $p_1$).

Find the standard matrix of T.

Now for some reason the answer to this assumes that

$p_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$p_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Which I don't really understand? It then simply performs the operation described in the description, namely leave $p_1$ as is, and substract $2p_1$ from $p_2$.

Why are the values for $p_1$ and $p_2$ assumed, where were these derived from?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear transformation is simply a linear map, which means the following conditions are satisfied:

$$f(u+v) = f(u) + f(v)$$
$$f(cu) = cf(u)$$

where $u$ and $v$ are vectors and $c$ is a scalar. You can find a more rigorous definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map).

Now, you do not need to know the inputs to write the transformation you describe. A linear transformation represents a linear system of equations, which you provided; thus, we can write the system in matrix form. The system is given by

$$ 
\begin{align}
p_1 &= p_1 \\
p_2 &= -2p_1 + p_2
\end{align}
$$
and in matrix form,

$$ [p’_1, p’_2]^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix} [p_1, p_2]^T$$

where $p’_1$ and $p’_2$ simply represent the transformed variables.

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you!